# Sharepoint 2010 content approval workflow disable email sending

Tags: workflow, content-approval

I want to use the out of the box content approval workflow. Is there a way to disable the sending of email acknowledgement for approval to both the approver and person who submitted the document?

Is it possible through code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, do you definitely want the workflow? Content approval on the list/doc lib may be more appropriate if you do not require delegation/cc/due dates and the other features that the workflow offers (as well as the enhanced audit).

Secondly, to disable the emails, you could edit the workflow within SharePoint Designer and remove the send email actions from the Approval task. Preferably you would recreate it as a reusable workflow, rather than edit the Globally reusable out of the box approval workflow (although you *could* do that if you wished).

Comment: Tim I did this but the initial workflow email doesn't seem to be in the approval workflow links. I removed all the other emails, but I still get the initial workflow email and I don't see it at all in the approval workflow actions. Please help. Where is the initial Workflow email and how can I remove it?